# gremlin request

Tags: neo4j, gremlin

How can i request with gremlin a limited list of nodes with properties of my choosing?

Something like:

```
g.V. 10 nodes with nodeType=="User", return only id, name and email.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
g.V.filter{it.nodeType=='User'}[0..9].transform(){it.id +  ' ' + it.name + ' ' + it.email}
```

Answer (score 2):

For speed, do filter{it.getProperty('nodeType').equals('User')}...

Answer (score 2):

Using TinkerPop 3+, that would be:

```
g.V().hasLabel('user').limit(10).valueMap(true, 'name', 'email')
```

Calling `valueMap(true)` returns both the `id` and the `label` of the traversed graph element.

For performance, it is now recommended to avoid lambdas and use Gremlin steps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Tinkerpop 3 and you have the "Type" you are are searching on defined as the node label then you can do something like this:

g.V.hasLabel('User')[0..10].valueMap.select('id','name','e-mail')

Note also that I think you need to specify [0..10] if you want 10 nodes and not [0..9]

However I totally defer to Marko's answer on performance as he understands the internals. I just like the clean feel of hasLabel().